# How to save CLCircularRegion to NSUserDeafults

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, core-location

I have an `CLCircularRegion` object that I want to save using `NSUserDeafults`,

I know I can't save objects to `NSUserDeafults` and in my custom object I have an `ToDictionary` func that converts the object to NSDictionary and then I save it.

but is subclassing `CLCircularRegion` and adding this func the only way to save it to `NSUserDeafults`? Or is there a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: @Paulw11 Good idea, thanks

Comment: You don't have to subclass, you just need a function (maybe in an extension  of CLCircularRegion) that converts the objects to / from dictionary.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding before saving with NSUserDefaults:

```
let savedRegion = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(region)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(savedRegion, forKey: "savedRegion")
```

Then unarchive to retrieve,

```
if let unarchivedRegion = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedRegion") {
 savedRegion = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(unarchivedRegion as! NSData) as? CLCircularRegion }
```